# array not reading data from file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I have a program that uses a 2d array to store some values. I have 2 questions. First My program isnt reading the data from my text file correctly. When it prints out the numbers in the array, I get all Zeros. What is wrong with my code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int ary [][13];

ofstream OutFile;
ifstream infile("NameAvg.txt");

//function prototype
void ReadIt (int [][13]); // Function call  ReadIntoArrayByRows(ary);
void WritePrintOutArray (int [][13]);

int main()
{
    //open/creates file to print to
    OutFile.open ("MyOutFile.txt");

    // Title and Heading 
    OutFile << "\nName and grade average\n";
    cout << "Name and grade average.\n\n";

    // Open and Reads .txt file for array
    ReadIt(ary);
    OutFile<<"\n-----------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n-----------------------------"<<endl;

    WritePrintOutArray(ary);
    OutFile<<"\n-----------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n-----------------------------"<<endl;

    //closes .txt file
    OutFile.close();
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void WritePrintOutArray(int ary[][13])
{
    int col,
        row;
    for(row=0;row<2;row++)
    {
    for(col=0;col<8;col++)
    {
        ary[2][13];
        cout<<ary[row][col];
        OutFile<<ary[row][col];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    OutFile<<endl;
    }
 }

 void ReadIt(int ary[][13])
 {
    int col,
        row=0;

    while(infile>>ary[row][0])
    {
    for(col=1;col<13;col++)
    {
        infile>>ary[row][col];
        row++;
    }
    infile.close();
    }
 }
```

My second question is can a single 2d array hold both a char data type and an int type? Or will I have to get all the data in the .txt file as a char and then convert the numbers into ints?

an example of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take infile.close(); out of the while loop.

Comment: What do you expect this line of code to do? `ary[2][13];`? If you are compiling with G++ or CLANG you might want to try turning on '-Wall'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the bug: your declaration of `ary` isn't reserving any space. You *must* give a number for both dimensions.

Second, you can make an array of two different things by putting those things in a structure.

```
struct It
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

It ary [MAX_ROWS][13];
```

Comment: so if I have 99 rows and 13 columns, I would use ary [99][13]

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory associated with the following array:

```
int ary [][13];
```

and I wonder why your compiler doesn't complain with something like *"storage size of ‘ary’ isn’t known"*. Anyway you should use `std::vector` instead. As to: *"can a single 2d array hold both a `char` data type and an `int` type?"* ~> you could define a custom type or alternatively you might use:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::pair<char, int> > > grades;
```

Although while looking at this matrix of pairs... something seems to be wrong and I'm sure that whatever is that you're trying to accomplish, there is a simpler way.

Also try to avoid using global variables. The way you use them makes the decomposition of your code into functions a bit useless. Your code is way too procedural for C++.